# Spring Security context is not retrieved from session

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm trying to get my security context but it seems to be store in ThreadLocale and so is different on each query.

I read that HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository should be used by default but it's obviously not the case :/

here is my pom

```
  <!-- Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

is there a way to force spring to use the session to store and retrieve context ?

Comment: The context that stored in ThreadLocal was getting from session by attribute "SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT"

Comment: Yes but spring is not using it to fill the ThreadLocal, that's my issue :)

Comment: Did you try to debug `SecurityContextPersistenceFilter` ?

Comment: I'm not getting in this filter :/